# Issue with 'unknown advertising packet type, invalid advertising data, advertising length corrected' Linux, Raspberry Pi, iOS, Homepod

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, homepod

I have been using a small c program I wrote to get bluetooth ble advertising packets from low cost bluetooth temperature sensors. A number of these sensors broadcast their temperature and humidity readings in either type 0 or type 4 bluetooth advertising packets. This gives me the ability to get this data from low cost sensors and not have to use the vendors app or cloud services.

This has been working great for months using a raspberry pi to collect this data and publish to MQTT. Recently the program started to fail. I tracked down the issue to the bluetooth stack crashing after some number and combination of it logging errors like these:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: unknown advertising packet type: 0xdf
Bluetooth: hci0: unknown advertising packet type: 0xd8
Bluetooth: hci0: Dropping invalid advertising data
Bluetooth: hci0: advertising data len corrected
```

I see these errors when I run my program on:
ARM Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Intel Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

The bluetooth stack failure and reload seems to occur most often on a Raspberry Pi with a USB Bluetooth adapter. A lower occurrence on Raspberry Pi using internal UART Bluetooth adapter, or any adapter on a beefier i5 x86 Ubuntu machine. However all log some combo of the above messages.

Here is where this starts to get a bit weird. I'm pretty sure the actions that are causing these messages and crashes are my using my iPhone to control my HomePods.....

This is moved quickly out of my pay grade. I have seen some reports of some similar messages well prior to HomePods at seem to indicate that the rate of advertising packets is exceeding some internal of Linux bluetooth stack. But, as I said, my system had been running for months with no issues. Until, I think, I introduced the HomePods into my home, and even then I think it might have been a new version of HomePod firmware that started the issues.

Any ideas or direction to explore would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: On Linux you can use `sudo btmon` to see a very detailed report of what is going on. Also, what API is you C program using? If it uses HCI commands directly then these bypass the Bluetooth daemon running on the system which can lead to conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas and questions.
I struggled with the many versions of bluez and dbus, it seems fragile requiring too many changes between version on different platforms.
So I fell back to talking directly to the device drivers via an hci_open_dev and read loop. I think this would be what you refer to as using HCI command directly. Yes, I am directly calling hci_* functions to set up my scanning parameters.

Could point me to some examples/docs of how to go thru the Bluetooth daemon, that would be super.
What sort of conflicts might occur from going the 'talk directly' to HCI device?

Comment: My rPi setup is processing about 8000 to 9000 advertising packets from 20 temperature sensors per hour, about 400 packets per device per hour. If the advertising packet is from another MAC address, I ignore it. And when I run the same code on a beefier i5 Linux machine in same location, about same number of packets seen per hour, so I do not seem to be taxing the rPi or missing packets with my stupid simple read loop.

Comment: ukBaz, found your stackoverflow posts and github. I'm reviewing your very helpful  info now, thx!

Comment: If you're comfortable with C and the low-level HCI commands then you probably want the BlueZ Bluetooth Management API which still goes through the daemon. Documentation at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt